# Changing increment value in for loop

Tags: php, arrays, loops, for-loop, increment

I am trying to set the correct value for $matchno.
It should increment by 1 only. Below is the code and example of the output array and I changed the array manually to show how I would like the array to be. The concern is only with $matchno

```
$max = 16;
$tournament_size = $max / 2;
$rounds = log($tournament_size) / log(2);

$curr = $tournament_size / 2;

$offset = $max;
$matchnoInBlock = -1;

for ($i = 0; $i < $rounds; $i++) 
{
    $inner = array();

    for ($i2 = 0; $i2 < $curr; $i2++)
    {
        $matchnoInBlock++;
        $matchno = $matchnoInBlock + $offset;

        $inner[] = array(0, 0, $matchno);
    }

    $lower_bracket_results[] = $inner;
    $lower_bracket_results[] = $inner;

    $curr /= 2;
}

echo '<pre>';
print_r($lower_bracket_results);
echo '</pre>';
```

Output of array:-

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 0
                    [1] => 0
                    [2] => 16
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 0
                    [1] => 0
                    [2] => 17
                )

            [2] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 0
                    [1] => 0
                    [2] => 18
                )

            [3] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 0
                    [1] => 0
                    [2] => 19
                )

        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 0
                    [1] => 0
                    [2] => 16
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 0
                    [1] => 0
                    [2] => 17
                )

            [2] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 0
                    [1] => 0
                    [2] => 18
                )

            [3] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 0
                    [1] => 0
                    [2] => 19
                )

        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 0
                    [1] => 0
                    [2] => 20
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 0
                    [1] => 0
                    [2] => 21
                )

        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 0
                    [1] => 0
                    [2] => 20
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 0
                    [1] => 0
                    [2] => 21
                )

        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 0
                    [1] => 0
                    [2] => 22
                )

        )

    [5] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 0
                    [1] => 0
                    [2] => 22
                )

        )

)
```

I would like the array to be like this: (only difference is with $matchno)

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 0
                    [1] => 0
                    [2] => 16
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 0
                    [1] => 0
                    [2] => 17
                )

            [2] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 0
                    [1] => 0
                    [2] => 18
                )

            [3] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 0
                    [1] => 0
                    [2] => 19
                )

        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 0
                    [1] => 0
                    [2] => 20
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 0
                    [1] => 0
                    [2] => 21
                )

            [2] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 0
                    [1] => 0
                    [2] => 22
                )

            [3] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 0
                    [1] => 0
                    [2] => 23
                )

        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 0
                    [1] => 0
                    [2] => 24
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 0
                    [1] => 0
                    [2] => 25
                )

        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 0
                    [1] => 0
                    [2] => 26
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 0
                    [1] => 0
                    [2] => 27
                )

        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 0
                    [1] => 0
                    [2] => 28
                )

        )

    [5] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 0
                    [1] => 0
                    [2] => 29
                )

        )

)
```

Any help on this thank you

Comment: You appear to increment $matchno as the first thing you do in the loop making it 17 rather than 16 that it started at.

Comment: How exactly do you want your array to look like? What's with this $x? Please clarify that first.

Comment: I edited my post to show exactly how the current array is and how I would like it changed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I got your question correctly, you just need to increment `$matchno` after assigning it to the array.

```
$matchno = 16;

for($x = 0; $x <= 3; $x++)
{
    $lower_bracket_results[0][$x][2] = $matchno;
    $matchno++;
}
```

or in a shorter fashion

```
$matchno = 16;

for($x = 0; $x <= 3; $x++)
{
    $lower_bracket_results[0][$x][2] = $matchno++;
}
```

### Edit after question edit

Since in your code you have a double

```
$lower_bracket_results[] = $inner;
$lower_bracket_results[] = $inner;
```

I assume you need to build 2 times this array but still incrementing the `$matchno`. Your issue here was that you were assigning the same `$inner` array to 2 entries in the array `$lower_bracket_results`. You can wrap the logic for creating the inner array in a function and call it 2 times. `$matchnoInBlock` is [passed by reference](http://php.net/manual/en/language.references.pass.php), so that inside the function you can increase the value of the same variable passed by the main context.

Here how it would look like, without changing much of how you wrote it:

```
<?php

function createInnerArray($curr, $offset, &$matchnoInBlock) {
    $inner = array();
    for ($i2 = 0; $i2 < $curr; $i2++)
    {
        $matchnoInBlock++;
        $matchno = $matchnoInBlock + $offset;

        $inner[] = array(0, 0, $matchno);
    }
    return $inner;
}

$max = 16;
$tournament_size = $max / 2;
$rounds = log($tournament_size) / log(2);

$curr = $tournament_size / 2;

$offset = 16;
$matchnoInBlock = -1;

for ($i = 0; $i < $rounds; $i++) 
{
    $lower_bracket_results[] = createInnerArray($curr, $offset, $matchnoInBlock);;
    $lower_bracket_results[] = createInnerArray($curr, $offset, $matchnoInBlock);;

    $curr /= 2;
}

echo '<pre>';
print_r($lower_bracket_results);
echo '</pre>';
```

Comment: The end result is being: (16, 17, 18, 19), (16, 17, 18, 19), (20, 21),  (20, 21), (22), (22) when it should be (16, 17, 18, 19), (20, 21, 22, 23), (24, 25), (26, 27), (28), (29). I am misunderstanding something.

Comment: If that's your output, you didn't post a piece of code that is iterating over the array. According to your code you're editing only inside key 0 of the first level of the array `$lower_bracket_results[0]`. Please edit your post to add the part that iterates over the first level

Comment: sorry I have changed the code hope this is clear for you

Comment: thank you for your time for helping me, exactly what i wanted.!